# Java library for scraping websites

Tags: library, java, scraping

I am looking for a good library to help me scrape information off of a certain website. The path the scraping has to follow can be rather dynamic, meaning that if the initial scrape is on a page of type 1, the next one will be on a page A, otherwise on a page B, etc; i.e. depending on the scraped info, it should follow another logic.

I have looked at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) as a possible help here, but there might be better options for it, specific to scraping, rather than testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a really nice library to parse and scrape HTML pages.

- It has a simple and easy to use API
- It is actively developed and [open source](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/)
- It has no dependencies to other libraries

I used it in a project and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Some open source web scraping libraries for Java are:

1. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)  (Recommend)
2. [Webscrap4j](http://dasnicdev.github.io/webscrap4j/)
3. [Mechanize](http://gistlabs.com/software/mechanize-for-java/)

But, Jsoup and Webscrap4j are very user friendly, and convenient to use with nice documentation.